# How do i prove that any subgroup of $A_5$ has order at most 12?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

I know this question has been answered [Other proofs that subgroups of $A_5$ have order at most 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360888/other-proofs-that-subgroups-of-a-5-have-order-at-most-12)

But i have difficulty in understanding that proof.The book says we can assume that $A_5$ has no normal subgroup.How to find the proof using this property ?

EDIT-
(I solved the previous question ( $A_5$ has no normal subgroup ) but i am not able to solve this problem ).

I have already mentioned that my question similar to [Other proofs that subgroups of $A_5$ have order at most 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360888/other-proofs-that-subgroups-of-a-5-have-order-at-most-12)  so please don't mark it as duplicate.

The book which i am talking about is  - Topics In Algerbra by Herstein. (2.10.15)

I am thankful if some can explain the same proof ( provided in link ).I have difficulty in understanding the homomorphic part of that answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have mentioned it in my question .I have difficulty in understanding that proof.I want to prove it using the fact that $A_5$ has no normal subgroup .

Comment: Then you comment that answer. Or you reproduce the answer within your question explaining *where* did you get stuck.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Any hint or suggestion from your side ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The user of that answer is probably not on stack exchange .Also i think that answer does not proves by using the property that $A_5$ has no normal subgroup

Comment: The answer linked by José Carlos is, in my opinion, as simple as one can expect, and I'm not sure there's another one simpler. To understand it, and understand other many important things as well, you need to know *action of a group on a set*, how such an action determines a homomorphism to a permutation group and etc. If you know this, you'll be able to understand why *the simple group* $\;A_5\;$ cannot have a subgroup of index $\;<5\;$ ...!

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for your comment.All the things you have mentioned i know.The part that i did not understood is  - the homomorphic map .A map is defined from one group to another .But how $S$ is a group ? can you explain the same answer in simple words in comments or in as a new answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Since you asked where i am stucked , i repeat a comment - The part that i did not understood is - the homomorphic map .A map is defined from one group to another .But how S is a group ? can you explain the same answer in simple words in comments or as a new answer. Can you explain me the homomorphic map ? Thanks.

Comment: The homomorphic map, both in the lin and in my answer, refers to a homomorphism from the *group* $\;A_5\;$ to the group of permutation on $\;l\;$ elements, whith $\;l=\,$ the number of cosets of the subgroup. This is **not** a subgroup of $\;A_5\;$, only a set upon which $\;A_5\;$ acts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;H\;$ be a subgroup of $\;A_5\;$ of order $\;>12\implies\;$ its index is $\;l<5\;$ . Then $\;A_5\;$ acts on the set of left cosets of $\;H\;$ in $\;G\;$ , and this determines a homomorphism $\;\phi:A_5\to S_l\;$ . Since $\;A_5\;$ is simple this homomorphis is acutaly a monomorphism (i.e., $\;1-1$) , and thus it is an injection, which of course is impossible as  $\;|A_5|=60>S_l\;$

Comment: Index can be equal to 4 .Suppose subgroup is of order 15

Comment: @Amit Of course, that was just a typo. Edited now, thanks.

Comment: Observe the above argument proves that a simple group *cannot* have a subgroup of any index $\;n\;$ such that the group's order is smaller than $\;n!\;$ ...In particular, infinite simple groups cannot have simple index subgroups

Comment: This is a very beautiful proof and it can be extended to show that for every $n\ge 5$, $A_n$ has no subgroups of order larger than $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$.

Comment: @Zvi Few doubt's - 1.How A5 will map to Sl . 2.I didn't knew that homomorphism from simple group is injection. can you explain that ? Thanks

Comment: A simple group $G$ has only two normal subgroups$\text{---}$$\{e\}$ and the whole $G$.  Since the kernel of any homomorphism of groups $\psi:G\to K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we have $\ker \psi=\{e\}$ or $=G$.  So, either $\phi$ is injective or trivial.  In the case at hand, $H$ is assumed to be a **proper** subgroup of $A_5$ (I forgot to add the word "proper").  So, $A_5$ cannot act on $A_5/H$ trivially.  That is, $\phi:A_5\to S_l$ can't be the trivial homomorphism, so it's injective.

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio  .Even after being duplicate question you took out time and cleared my doubt.Math SE people should understand that there can be slow learner's .

Comment: Thanks @Zvi You also cleared my important doubt through comment.

Comment: @zvi How to prove that $ϕ$ is homomorphism

Comment: @DonAntonio How to prove that $ϕ$ is homomorphism

Comment: @Hansie That $\;\phi\;$ is a homomorphism  *determined by the action* of $\;A_5\;$ on the left cosets of $\;H\;$ ... This is standard stuff in Actions of Groups on sets and etc., as I wrote in the comments below your question and you said you know all these things...

Answer (score 0):

$A_5$ has order 60. Thus, any proper subgroup $H$ of order larger than 12 must have order 15, 20, or 30. Any subgroup of order 30 would have index 2, so would be normal, contradicting your previous result. Thus, $H$ must have order 15 or 20.

Now, both 15 and 20 are multiples of 5, so $H$ must contain an element of order 5. Up to conjugation, that element is $(1,2,3,4,5)$. If $H$ has order 15, then it also contains an element of order $3$, which must be a 3-cycle. But running through each possible 3-cycle:

$(1,2,3)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 = (1,4)(2,5)$, which has order 2, so $H$ has even order, a contradiction.
$(1,2,4)(1,2,3,4,5)^4 = (2,3)(4,5)$, so again, $H$ has even order. 
$(1,3,5)(1,2,3,4,5)^4 = (1,2)(3,4)$, so again, $H$ has even order.

And all others are conjugate (as a whole) to those, so symmetrically, have the same orders. Thus, there is no subgroup of order 15.

Thus, $H$, if it exists, must have order 20, so must contain an element of order 2, which must be a product of two disjoint 2-cycles. Again, running through the possibilities:

$(1,2)(3,4)(1,2,3,4,5) = (1,3,5)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(1,3)(2,4)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 = (1,5,2)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(1,3)(2,5)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 = (1,5,4)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(1,4)(2,5)(1,2,3,4,5) = (3,5,4)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(1,5)(2,3)(1,2,3,4,5) = (2,4,5)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(1,5)(3,4)(1,2,3,4,5) = (2,3,5)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(2,3)(4,5)(1,2,3,4,5) = (1,2,4)$, so $H$ has order 60.
$(2,4)(3,5)(1,2,3,4,5)^2 = (1,3,2)$, so $H$ has order 60.

Now, you'll notice that I've missed a few permutations, namely:

$(1,2)(3,5)$
$(1,3)(4,5)$
$(1,4)(2,3)$
$(1,5)(2,4)$
$(2,5)(3,4)$

With these, we have:
$(1,2)(3,5)(1,2,3,4,5) = (1,3)(4,5)$,
$(1,3)(4,5)(1,2,3,4,5) = (1,4)(2,3)$,
$(1,4)(2,3)(1,2,3,4,5) = (1,5)(2,4)$,
$(1,5)(2,4)(1,2,3,4,5) = (2,5)(3,4)$, and 
$(2,5)(3,4)(1,2,3,4,5) = (1,2)(3,5)$,

so if any one of these lies in $H$, all of them do. Further, these five elements, along with the powers of $(1,2,3,4,5)$ form a subgroup, of order 10. But if $H$ contains any other element, it must be one of order 2 or 5 (else $H$ would have order a multiple of 3): the order 2 cases have been covered above, and all give $H = A_5$. Checking the elements of order 5 that aren't already in there:

$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,2,3,5,4) = (1,3)(2,5)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,2,4,3,5) = (1,4)(2,5)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,2,4,5,3)^2 = (1,5,4)$, 
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,2,5,3,4)^2 = (1,3,2)$, 
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,2,5,4,3) = (1,5,2)$, 
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,3,2,4,5) = (1,4)(3,5)$, 
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,3,2,5,4) = (1,5,3)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,3,4,2,5)^2 = (3,5,4)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,3,4,5,2) = (2,4)(3,5)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,3,5,4,2) = (2,5,3)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,4,2,3,5)^2 = (1,5,2)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,4,3,2,5) = (1,5,4)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,4,3,5,2) = (2,5,4)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,4,5,2,3)^2 = (2,4,3)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,4,5,3,2) = (3,5,4)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,5,2,3,4) = (1,3)(2,4)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,5,2,4,3) = (1,4,2)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,5,3,2,4) = (1,4,3)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,5,3,4,2) = (2,4,3)$,
$(1,2,3,4,5)(1,5,4,2,3) = (1,3,2)$.

So if $H$ contains any of these, it is all of $A_5$. Thus, there is no subgroup of $A_5$ of order 20, and hence no proper subgroup of order more than 12.

[NB: there are some pretty massive time-saving options available here: I went for keeping things as elementary as possible]

Comment: It might help if you use the fact that any group of order $15$ is cyclic.  But there is no element of $A_5$ of order $15$.

Comment: Indeed, that's one of the time-saving options that I mentioned.