# How is $A_5$ is the union of cosets $H, gH, g^2H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

Working on a proof to show that $A_5$ has no subgroup H of order 15 or 20.

I am obstructed at this point: if $g$ is an element of the group $A_5$ of order 5, why is that if g is not in a subgroup H, then $A_5$ is the union of cosets H, gH, $g^2$H?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995244/how-do-i-prove-that-any-subgroup-of-a-5-has-order-at-most-12?noredirect=1 this may help you

Comment: It did not @Koushik_halder :(
Can you elaborate please?

Comment: any subgroup of $A_5$ has order at most 12.Then,is it possible that $A_5$ has a subgroup of order 15 or 20?

Comment: It's not. I am able to map out elements and see the structure: 24 of order 5, 20 order 3, and 15 order 2, and identity. But I am compelled to show that $A_5$ is the union of the cosets I mentioned above which I cannot figure how to do.

Comment: If it's a normal subgroup, then it must be a union of some conjugate classes of $A_5$, one of which should be the class containing the identity, i.e. of size $1$. The other conjugate classes have sizes $20$, $15$, $12$, $12$. No sum of those numbers including $1$ is a divisor of $60$ other than $1=1$ and $60=20+15+12+12+1$.

Comment: @WilfredoGuillermo The 24 elements of order 5 split into 2 conjugate classes in $A_5$, those of $(12345)$ and $(12354)$.

Answer (score 1):

The most important observation is that the cosets $H, gH, g^2H, g^3H, g^4H$ should be disjoint if $g$ is an element of order $5$ and $g$ is not in the subgroup $H$. To show this, let $n$ be the least positive power of $g$ that is in $H$. Since $g$ is not in $H$, $n > 1$. But also $n$ is a factor of $5$, since $g^5 = e$ is in $H$. So $n = 5$.

When $12 < |H| < 24$, this leads to a contradiction because $H$ cannot contain all elements of order $5$, so it is possible to find an element $g$ of order $5$ not in $H$. Yet, $H, gH, g^2H, g^3H, g^4H$ are disjoint sets in $A_5$ containing more than $60$ elements altogether, when $A_5$ only has $60$ elements to begin with.

You may phrase this in terms of $A_5$ being the union of cosets $H, gH, g^2H$ by reversing the logic and only considering three cosets (because four cosets would give us more than $60$ elements), but I think the way I have written is simpler.

Comment: Can you explain why this is? "The most important observation is that the cosets ,,2,3,4 should be disjoint if  is an element of order 5 and  is not in the subgroup "

Comment: The idea is in the next sentence: if $g^{i}H = g^{j}H$, then $g^{i-j}$ is in $H$, which can only happen if $i-j$ is a multiple of $5$.