# Abstract Algebra: Prove that A5 has no proper subgroups with order 15 or greater.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have thought of this and looked at other answers but the answer is not clear. We have not learned about Sylow yet and also we have not learned about the kernel. 
So far, I know that A5 has order 60 with subgroups of orders 1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12,15,20, and 30. So, I know it must be shown that 15, 20, and 30 are not proper subgroups. 
I considered that these subgroups are cyclic but I'm not understanding how this relates to the proof. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you remind me what proper means? I’ve usually understood it as a subgroup that is strictly smaller than the whole group.

Comment: @Clayton: What is your potential confusion?

Comment: Groups of order 15 must be cyclic, but groups of order 20 or 30 need not be cyclic. Also, have you actually *proven* that a group of order 15 must be cyclic?

Comment: He stated he knows that A5 has subgroups of order 15,20, and 30 (which, according to how I understand proper, would be a counterexample to the statement that A5 has no proper subgroups of order $\geq15$).

Comment: @Clayton: I understood that to mean "possible orders", but I see your point.

Comment: Another duplicate is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357225/subgroups-of-a-5-have-order-at-most-12).